# Have + verb-ing vs have + participle

Tags: grammar

In response to Rachel's good-bye email, James wrote:
"Rachel, you've been wonderful to have working with us at the studio."

Is "to have working" correct ? Is this acceptable in Canadian English ?

I would have written "to have worked ..."

Comment: We would more naturally say "Rachel, it's been wonderful to have you working with us at the studio", or "Rachel, it's been wonderful having you work with us at the studio".

Comment: WHo is Rachel?  Who is James? What is the studio?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like James has started with one sentence and finished with another.

He started with "Rachel, you've been wonderful [as a colleague]" But then changed his mind and tried to write "It has been wonderful to have you working with us". Here the dummy pronoun "it" refers to the phrase "to have you working with us".  (The dummy pronoun structure is better than "To have you working with us has been wonderful", because of end weighting)

The end result is a bit of a mess, and not an example of well written English. This kind of error is quite common in speech, and in emails that are written and sent without proofreading.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is correct, in all English including Canadian. It's a bit clunky, but it works.

To have worked is incorrect.